Bluetooth Drivers
I dont know much about Bluetooth drivers in Ubuntu (im using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS), but my desktop has a TP-Link Archer TX20E V2 and its always failing and i have to reinstall the rtw89 drivers that i found by just google searching
Can someone help me to understand how this drivers works? My kernel version is 6.5.0-28-generic and this is my output in lspci command:
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852]
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:5470]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw89_8852be
    Kernel modules: rtw_8852be
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 046d:c092 Logitech, Inc. G203 LIGHTSYNC Gaming Mouse
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c548 Logitech, Inc. USB Receiver
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:3570 IMC Networks Bluetooth Radio
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hu

do I need to install other drivers? maybe there is no support for this networks card in Ubuntu? im really confused
